# How do I view TabView in Title Bar? In UWP WinUI 2 Application

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I want to view TabView in title bar like image below.[image]
I'm using UWP WinUI 2.

I'm trying to view my TabView in title bar. But TabView is viewing under title bar.

My MainPage.xaml code:

```xml
<muxc:TabView Grid.Row="2">
    <muxc:TabViewItem Header="New Tab">
                
    </muxc:TabViewItem>
</muxc:TabView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy:

In your xaml code:
This piece of code adds a ShellTitlebarInset and a CustomDragRegion to the TabView. This is needed, to add a margin to the left and right side of the window.

```
<muxc:TabView x:Name="tabView">
    <muxc:TabView.TabStripHeader>
        <Grid x:Name="ShellTitlebarInset" Background="Transparent" />
    </muxc:TabView.TabStripHeader>
    <muxc:TabView.TabStripFooter>
        <Grid x:Name="CustomDragRegion" MinWidth="188" Loaded="CustomDragRegion_Loaded" Background="Transparent" />
    </muxc:TabView.TabStripFooter>
    
    <muxc:TabViewItem Header="Tab1"/>
    <muxc:TabViewItem Header="Tab2"/>
    <muxc:TabViewItem Header="Tab3"/>
</muxc:TabView>
```

In your MainPage:

The LayoutMetricsChanged event handles the FlowDirection either from LeftToRight or RightToLeft to add the specific margin to the CustomDragRegion and ShellTitlebarInset.

```
private void CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar sender, object args)
{
    if (FlowDirection == FlowDirection.LeftToRight)
    {
        CustomDragRegion.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayRightInset;
        ShellTitlebarInset.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayLeftInset;
    }
    else
    {
        CustomDragRegion.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayLeftInset;
        ShellTitlebarInset.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayRightInset;
    }

    CustomDragRegion.Height = ShellTitlebarInset.Height = sender.Height;
}


//Make sure to extend the view after the CustomDragRegion loaded, otherwise the tabs may clip under the minimize, maximize and close buttons of the window:
private void CustomDragRegion_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    coreTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged += CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged;

    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(CustomDragRegion);
}
```

Here also the official documentation from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/tab-view